# My iOS app should run on lockscreen

Tags: ios, objective-c, io

I've got an iOS project from a customer that the app should run on lockscreen mode. Please check the below link which the customer shared with me.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/weather-lock-screen-free/id433369569?mt=8
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lockscreen+/id437555991?mt=8

I don't want to use jailbreaking method. So if its possible please let me know what are the steps to develop the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your customer understand that applications do not run on the lockscreen? The examples linked just make pictures that can be set as the lockscreen background. The portion shown on the lockscreen cannot have any buttons, functions, or anything that ever changes, as they are just pictures.

If you would like to proceed with making pictures, you would simply create an image of the appropriate size (whatever the device's resolution is) and format the contents so it fits nicely underneath the lock screen. Then save the image and instruct the user to set it as their background.

Comment: This is an Android feature. It does not exist on iOS.

Comment: Right, leave it alone Apple will not even let you set the wallpaper programmatically via your app. User needs to manually set it using Settings menu if your phone's not jailbroken.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, So would like to confirm that we can't add button or functions on lockscreen but instead of that we can add image. Neither can i launch app once unlocked the iPhone?